# How to make LibreOffice Calc to not to hide unfit content of a cell when the folowing cell contains data?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

If I enter a long string into a cell it (the string) is normally displayed in its whole, taking a part of the next cell area. Line A (1) on the picture below is an example.

If I enter a long string into a cell it (the string) is truncated and a red triangle is placed into the cell to indicate this if the next cell contains any data. Line B (2) on the picture below is an example.

I would like to turn off this behaviour (truncation) to acheive the effect illustrated by the line C (3) of the picture (I've produced it with a graphics editor now). Is this possible? If yes, how?

[image: Illustration]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting the cell contents by selecting it and then right click 'delete contents'. I then re-pasted the content back in and it no longer truncated.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a cell, written by somebody else, 
which occupied more than one line.

->

This is the complete

information encountered

within this specific

cell.

---

It had all that extra space at the end, and no matter what I tried,
couldn't get it to write it like this:

This is the complete information encountered within this specific cell.

I had to manually erase all spaces and it was fixed!

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the cell and select `Clear direct formatting`.